# Method to find user data to be deleted from the dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to pull specific info based on the input of a user. Once the info is pulled, it will be deleted. The info is stored in dictionaries that are inside of a list. As of now, what I have is as follows:

```
if selection == '3':
    print('Please enter in the information of the user you are looking for:\n')
    remove_first_name = input("User's first name:\t")
    remove_last_name = input("User's last name:\t")

    for item_to_delete in all_users:
        if item_to_delete['First name'] == remove_first_name and item_to_delete['Last name'] == remove_last_name:
            delete_item = item_to_delete
                input('Is this the user you are looking for?\t', delete_item)
                break
        else:
            print('Sorry. There is no user found with that information. Please try again')
            delete_item = None
```

When running, I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muturi/Test_file.py", line 69, in <module>
    input('Is this the user you are looking for?\t', delete_item)
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

Any and all assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: `input()` expects only a single argument. Why are you passing `delete_item` to it? To take input into a variable use assignment `delete_item = input(...)`

Comment: As you can see from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) for `input()`, it only accepts a single argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` method only requires 1 argument, but you're giving it 2. You should format the question first, before passing it to the `input()` method. So:

```
input("Is this the user you're lookinf for?\t%s" % (delete_item))
```

This will replace the `"%s"` in the string with the value of `delete_item`. The `input()` method then receives just one argument.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` takes only one single parameter. If you are trying to confirm if `delete_item` is the correct item to be deleted use:

```
delete_item = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> input('Is this the user you are looking for?\t' + str(delete_item))
Is this the user you are looking for?   {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
''
>>>
```